# Django Hidden menu on dashboard

Tags: python, django

Now I want to hidden menu on Django by user 's role .
I have three role

```
is_shop
is_customer
is_brocker
```

Any one have any solution to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In your template you can use `if` statements and display the blocks you want like this:

```
<div id="submenu">
    {% if request.user.is_shop %}
    <div id="shop-menu">
    {% else if request.user.is_customer %}
    <div id="customer-menu">
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use template engine to render your page, it's easy, just pass user's role to template engine before render it.

And if you separate frontend and backend, you must check user' role in your frontend js.